# ImageMagick create circle count on top of image

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

Hey all I have the following Magick.net code:

```
List<string> lFiles = new List<string>();
bool isBlankImage = false;

lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\1.jpg");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\blank.png");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\blank.png");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\blank.png");
lFiles.Add(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\blank.png");

IMagickImage roundImg = new MagickImage();
IMagickImage mask = new MagickImage();
IMagickImage shadow = new MagickImage();
IMagickImage result = new MagickImage();

foreach (string tempFBProfileImg in lFiles)
{
     roundImg = new MagickImage(tempFBProfileImg);

     if (Regex.IsMatch(tempFBProfileImg.ToLower(), @"\bblank.png\b"))
     {
         result.Extent(360, 100, Gravity.West);
         images.Add(result);
         isBlankImage = true;
         break;
     }
     else
     {
         mask = new MagickImage("xc:black", 100, 100);
         mask.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.White;
         mask.Draw(new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 90));
         mask.HasAlpha = false;

         roundImg.Resize(100, 100);
         roundImg.Composite(mask, CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);
         roundImg.Draw(new DrawableStrokeColor(MagickColors.Black), 
                       new DrawableStrokeWidth(1),
                       new DrawableFillColor(MagickColors.None),
                       new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 90));

         shadow = new MagickImage("xc:none", 100, 100);
         shadow.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.Black;
         shadow.Draw(new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 90));
         shadow.Blur(0, 5);

         roundImg.Composite(shadow, CompositeOperator.DstOver);

         images.Add(roundImg);
         images.First().BackgroundColor = MagickColors.None;

         result = images.SmushHorizontal(-35);
         result.Resize(100, 100);
         result.Write(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\final2.png");
     }                                    
}

var imgText = new MagickImage(MagickColors.Blue, 0, 0);

imgText.Settings.FontPointsize = 24;
imgText.BackgroundColor = MagickColors.White;
imgText.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.Black;
imgText.Settings.TextAntiAlias = true;
imgText.Settings.FontFamily = "Arial";
imgText.Read("label: 10+", 45, 25);
string caption = "label:10+";
//imgText = new MagickImage(caption, settings);
//imgText.Draw(new DrawableText(100, 20, "10+"));
imgText.Page = new MagickGeometry(300, 100, 0, 0);

result.Composite(imgText, CompositeOperator.Over);
result.Write(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\final2.png");
```

And this comes out looking like this:

[image]

But what I am looking to want it to look like is this:

[image]

I'm having issues with just making a red circle with a black outline and shadow with the text XX+ inside it. Also, I've looked high and low to find out how i can position it where I need it but I am unable to find it. I thought that MagickGeometry would be it but it turns out that its not.

**Update 1**

Changing some code I now get this:

[image]

Changed code:

```
roundImg.Composite(mask, CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);
roundImg.Draw(new DrawableStrokeColor(MagickColors.Black),
              new DrawableStrokeWidth(1),
              new DrawableFillColor(MagickColors.None),
              new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 90));
imgText.Composite(roundImg, CompositeOperator.Over);
imgText.Settings.FontPointsize = 24;
imgText.BackgroundColor = MagickColors.Red;
imgText.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.White;
imgText.Settings.TextAntiAlias = true;
imgText.Settings.FontFamily = "Arial";
imgText.Read("label: 10+", 45, 25);
//string caption = "label:This is a very long caption line";
//imgText = new MagickImage(caption, settings);
//imgText.Draw(new DrawableText(100, 20, "10+"));
imgText.Page = new MagickGeometry(360, 100, 0, 0);
result.Composite(imgText, CompositeOperator.Over);
result.Write(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\final2.png");
```

**update 2**

Ok I have the code correct for the round circle with number in it:

```
MagickImage circleText = new MagickImage(MagickColors.Transparent, 29, 29);
MagickImage circle = new MagickImage(MagickColors.Transparent, 29, 29);

circleText.Settings.BorderColor = MagickColors.Black;              
circleText.Settings.FontPointsize = 16;
circleText.Settings.FontWeight = ImageMagick.FontWeight.Bold;
circleText.BackgroundColor = MagickColors.Transparent;
circleText.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.White;
circleText.Settings.TextGravity = Gravity.Center;
circleText.Settings.TextAntiAlias = true;
circleText.Settings.FontFamily = "Arial";
circleText.Border(2);
circleText.Read("label: 10+", 29, 29);
circle.Draw(new DrawableStrokeColor(MagickColors.Black),
            new DrawableStrokeWidth(1),
            new DrawableFillColor(MagickColors.Red),
            new DrawableCircle(14, 14, 10, 1));
circleText.Composite(circle, CompositeOperator.DstOver);

result.Composite(circleText, CompositeOperator.Over);
result.Write(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\final2.png");
```

Which produces the image:

[image]

But now I can not seem to get the border for the text to show up and I'm still stuck on how to move the circle to its intended spot?

**update 3**

I finally got it to move over where I need it to be using this code:

```
MagickImage circleText = new MagickImage(MagickColors.Transparent, 29, 29);
MagickImage circle = new MagickImage(MagickColors.Transparent, 29, 29);
MagickImage _shadow = new MagickImage();

circleText.Settings.BorderColor = MagickColors.Black;
circleText.Settings.FontPointsize = 16;
circleText.Settings.FontWeight = ImageMagick.FontWeight.Bold;
circleText.BackgroundColor = MagickColors.Transparent;
circleText.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.White;
circleText.Settings.TextGravity = Gravity.Center;
circleText.Settings.TextAntiAlias = true;
circleText.Settings.FontFamily = "Arial";
circleText.Border(2);
circleText.Read("label: 10+", 29, 29);
circle.Draw(new DrawableStrokeColor(MagickColors.Black),
                    new DrawableStrokeWidth(1),
                    new DrawableFillColor(MagickColors.Red),
                    new DrawableCircle(14, 14, 10, 1));

_shadow = new MagickImage("xc:none", 29, 29);
_shadow.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.Black;
_shadow.Draw(new DrawableCircle(14, 14, 10, 1));
_shadow.Blur(0, 15);

circle.Composite(_shadow, CompositeOperator.DstOver);

circleText.Composite(circle, CompositeOperator.DstOver);

result.Composite(circleText, 68, 9, CompositeOperator.Over);
result.Write(@"C:\Users\David\Pictures\final2.png");
```

**BUT** when I try to add the shadow to the circle it comes out looking like this:

[image]

Not sure why the shadow is coming out being a square when its using the exact circle x,y,w,h as the original red circle...

Comment: Still looking for help with this.

Comment: 3 years later but the MagickImage.Shadow() method can now be used to make the shadow which may fix your problem